# Which deep reinforcement library works best with pygame

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm seeking a reinforcement library that works well with custom pygame environments.

Thank you very much.

Please do not close my question; I have been researching for a long time and have yet to find a solution. Even a single comment might be really beneficial to me. Thanks for your patience. Even one comment can be very useful to me. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly straightforward, but you can [create a custom gym environment](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-a-custom-openai-gym-environment-for-stock-trading-be532be3910e) to "wrap" your pygame, then create a DQN agent to interact with that environment. See [here](https://gym.openai.com/envs/CartPole-v0/) for some solutions to premade gym environments.